# implemente Custom model to my imgLabelin ERROR I/tflite ( 8933): Replacing 71 node(s) with delegate (TfLiteXNNPackDelegate) node, yieldin

Tags: flutter, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit

I'm trying to implement Custom model to my `imgLabeling`.

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:google_mlkit_image_labeling/google_mlkit_image_labeling.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String imageLabel = "";
  late ImageLabeler imageLabeler;

  void getImageLabels(XFile image) async {
    final inputImage = InputImage.fromFilePath(image.path);

    List<ImageLabel> labels = await imageLabeler.processImage(inputImage);
    StringBuffer sb = StringBuffer();
    for (ImageLabel imgLabel in labels) {
      String lblText = imgLabel.label;
      double confidence = imgLabel.confidence;
      sb.write(lblText);
      sb.write(' : ');
      sb.write((confidence * 100).toStringAsFixed(2));
      sb.write('%');
    }
    imageLabeler.close();
    imageLabel = sb.toString();
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<String> _getModel(String assetPath) async {
    if (io.Platform.isAndroid) {
      return 'flutter_assets/$assetPath';
    }
    final path = '${(await getApplicationSupportDirectory()).path}/$assetPath';
    await io.Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
    final file = io.File(path);
    if (!await file.exists()) {
      final byteData = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
      await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer
          .asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));
    }
    return file.path;
  }

  void _initializeLabeler() async {
    const path = 'assets/ml/kiri-v1.tflite';
    final modelPath = await _getModel(path);
    final options = LocalLabelerOptions(modelPath: modelPath);
    imageLabeler = ImageLabeler(options: options);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _initializeLabeler();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    imageLabeler.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  File? image;
  Future pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    try {
      final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: source);
      if (image == null) return;
      final imageTemorary = File(image.path);
      setState(() {
        this.image = imageTemorary;
      });
      getImageLabels(image);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      print('fail to pick an Image:$e');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text('Kiri demo'),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Spacer(),
            image != null
                ? Image.file(
                    image!,
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )
                : FlutterLogo(
                    size: 200,
                  ),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => pickImage(ImageSource.camera),
              icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
              label: Text('Camera'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              onPressed: () => pickImage(ImageSource.gallery),
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_photo_alternate_outlined),
              label: Text('Galery  '),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text(
              imageLabel,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> E/flutter ( 8933): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ImageLabelDetectorError,
> com.google.mlkit.common.MlKitException: Failed to initialize detector.
> Input tensor has type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying
> NormalizationOptions metadata to preprocess input images., null, null)

Here is the console:

> I/tflite  ( 8933): Replacing 71 node(s) with delegate
> (TfLiteXNNPackDelegate) node, yielding 1 partitions. I/SurfaceView(
> 8933): surfaceChanged (720,1510) 1 #1
> io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterSurfaceView{39f184f V.E......
> ......ID 0,0-720,1510} I/ViewRootImpl@f714781MainActivity:
> updateBoundsLayer: shouldReparent = true t =
> android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@be55036 sc =
> Surface(name=Bounds for -
> com.example.imagelabel/com.example.imagelabel.MainActivity@2)/@0x2a1b5ac
> frame = 1 I/SurfaceView( 8933): applySurfaceTransforms: t =
> android.view.SurfaceControl$Transaction@4ba94e5 surfaceControl =
> Surface(name=SurfaceView -
> com.example.imagelabel/com.example.imagelabel.MainActivity@39f184f@2)/@0x33cf275
> frame = 1 E/native  ( 8933): E0421 14:51:46.114804   16014
> calculator_graph.cc:809] NOT_FOUND: CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in
> Run:  E/native  ( 8933): Calculator::Open() for node
> "ClassifierClientCalculator" failed: #vk Input tensor has type
> kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions metadata
> to preprocess input images.
> [type.googleapis.com/mediapipe.StatusList='\n\xed\x01\x08\x05\x12\xbb\x01\x43\x61lculator::Open()
> for node "ClassifierClientCalculator" failed: #vk Input tensor has
> type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions
> metadata to preprocess input
> images.\x1a+\n$tflite::support::TfLiteSupportStatus\x12\x03\x32\x30\x38']
> E/native  ( 8933): === Source Location Trace: ===  E/native  ( 8933):
> third_party/mediapipe/framework/tool/status_util.cc:139 E/native  (
> 8933):  E/native  ( 8933): E0421 14:51:46.115117   16014
> pipeline_jni.cc:96] NOT_FOUND: CalculatorGraph::Run() failed in Run:
> E/native  ( 8933): Calculator::Open() for node
> "ClassifierClientCalculator" failed: #vk Input tensor has type
> kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions metadata
> to preprocess input images.
> [type.googleapis.com/mediapipe.StatusList='\n\xed\x01\x08\x05\x12\xbb\x01\x43\x61lculator::Open()
> for node "ClassifierClientCalculator" failed: #vk Input tensor has
> type kTfLiteFloat32: it requires specifying NormalizationOptions
> metadata to preprocess input
> images.\x1a+\n$tflite::support::TfLiteSupportStatus\x12\x03\x32\x30\x38']

The labels shoould come under the buttons but nothing appears there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/custom-models#model-compatibility

```
The data is UINT8 or FLOAT32 type. If the input tensor type is FLOAT32, it must specify the NormalizationOptions by attaching Metadata.
```

Comment: I  did some testing with the API models and works 100% .U.U I'll rather do a new and better model cuz  to it was a "test model "(it does 100% work  with the tflite package cuz I test it )  I  think u can set the options  with the tflite_helper package but it's deprecatted